# file_get_contents() of external resource may going out time?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Hello i would like to know if i use `file_get_contents()` for external resource but the server where's the file doesn't work or is too late what appen....

Example i tried:

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents('https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/1.0_week_age.kml');
print_r($string);

//file of external resource is kml

?>
```

works for how long ?
And if going "out time" **$string** will be empty ?

Thanks a lot and sorry for my english :)

Comment: You can simply test your question with an invalid url.

Comment: Why do you think people write manuals? http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#refsect1-function.file-get-contents-returnvalues

Comment: @u_mulder That there were people who read its and wrote the answers on StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your own timeout using this:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300); // 5 minutes
```